# C language and miniboards

Tags: c, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am a student, at the moment I finished my first language C fundamentals course. I like boards like Arduino, Raspberry etc etc...
In particular I prefer Raspberry but the main programming language is Python. As I already say, I know only C. 
Which boards do you suggest me for begin?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The base of boards programming. I won't make a media center station or other things like this.
I will use it to control servomotors, led, do own project. 
I hope that I give the idea.

Comment: Raspberry pi is basically just a very cheap computer. There's nothing stopping you from writing c code on one. Can you be more specific about the problem you're having?

Comment: I won't have a pc. I will do c code to program the boards to do something. I am a newer of this world, so I can't be more specific.

My idea is:  I have a problem. I write a code to program the board and solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like the Arduino better, it's a micro-controller specifically designed for things like controlling servo motors and LED's, and the implementation language is a variant of C. That said, the Arduino is limited, it's not a fully fledged computer like the Pi is so your options will be limited. I would recommend you do your own research on the capabilities and limitations of the two and decide which would be best for the projects you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are true, as I wrote in the comment above, this board will be a board to learn the bases, not for do complex project. In these days I will search other informations and after this month I will choose.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use Raspberry Pi to control other hardware using the general purpose I/O pins. In this case there are libraries for both [Python](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio/python-rpigpio-api) and [C](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio/c-wiringpi-api) available to access those pins.

Comment: Yes! It is what I was trying to say.
Which boards is better to begin?

Comment: Raspberry Pi is a fully functional computer running linux, and you can write your code on the device itself. I haven't used Arduino myself, but my understanding is that you program it on a separate machine then load your code onto the board. I've found working on a Raspberry Pi to be very pleasant, I can't speak for Arduino.

Comment: Thank  you for the answer.  Yes with Raspberry Pi I have a pc, instead, with arduino I have just a board. I haven't  to do big project at the moment. This first board will be the first board to learn the bases. I don't know, I'm uncertain. I'll wait for others suggestions.